# How do I Search and Download a Python file from my Localhost Webserver?

Tags: python, search

I want to create a Python file so that I can download files from my localhost web server. (only for Python files!)

I'm not looking for other programs etc. that already exist, but want to do it myself.

When I run my script in a Python shell, I should be able to say what I'm looking for. e.g. Hello.py file and then search for a file called Hallo.py, if it exists it should be downloaded.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Using the [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) module, you can make HTTP GET requests to specific endpoints.

```
import requests
response = requests.get('localhost/anyfile.py')
file_text = response.text
with open('filename.py', 'w+') as fp:
   fp.write(file_text)
```